# django-mptt filter without breaking the tree

Tags: django, model, filter, tree, mptt

I'm using django-mptt for a Article model in my Django application. If I want to get all Articles which are set to for example hidden, I could do

```
Article.objects.filter(hidden=False)
```

but that would break the mptt-tree. How can I filter on my queryset in such a way that not only does it exclude all hidden articles, but also the childs of those nodes and that way maintain the integrity of the tree so that I still can use the tree_info template tag?

Comment: In what way does that query "break" the tree?

Comment: Well by doing that a node might lose it's parent. :o

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue. I would like to remove a node and all of its children.

Here is how I manage to do that:

```
class FolderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ('name', 'parent')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(FolderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance is not None:
            exclude_ids = [f.id for f in self.instance.get_descendants(
                include_self=True)]

            self.fields['parent'].queryset = self.fields['parent'].queryset \
                .exclude(pk__in=exclude_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution: just set all the children to hidden as well.